# Existence of certain hyper surface with no lines in $\mathbb{P}^3_k$ for an infinite field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ Be an infinite field.

Show that for any $n>3$ there exists a degree $n$ hypersurface $f(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3)$, so deg$f = n$, that contains no lines.

I’ve been trying to figure this out / have been looking for a proof of this statement for a week now but no luck. Does anyone have a proof for this?